# why this code takes one less input from standard input?

Tags: c++, string, io, getline

Giving input as:

```
Input:
    3
    1 2 3 
    4 5 6 7
    8 9 10 11 12
Expected Output:
    1 2 3
    4 5 6 7
    8 9 10 11 12
```

But it is giving the Output-

```
 1 2 3
 4 5 6 7
```

Why it is not giving the last line ? Is there any mistake in my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{   string str;
    getline(cin,str,'\n');
    cout<<str<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string.h` sure??

Comment: Why do people feel the need to punish someone with downvotes for asking a question just because it's a duplicate? It's not at all obvious how you would search for the answer to this. I thought the question was adequately asked.

Comment: @Mark Since when are DVs for _"punishing"_ a user? They are about usefulness of content. As a user with such high rep you should well know that.

Comment: @user0042 since downvotes affect your reputation, which affects the ability you have to use the site, it is indeed punishment whether that's intended or not.

Comment: @Mark Well, we require (force) users to do some research before asking. You're right insofar that the duplicate isn't obvious, though not impossible to find a lot of hints about that specific behavior of formatted text extraction and `std::getline()`. If at all we're punishing _laziness_ in research to keep Stack Overflow clean and useful. Answering such questions only slow down the process of roombaing such frequent questions. So please don't if you know better.

Comment: @user0042 i am new user to stackoveflow... i am getting the point what u are saying .....i will do more research on any quesiton before submitting next time..

Comment: _@vikas2cc_ @Mark Mission of voting system accomplished.

Comment: @user0042 I'm not fond of the roomba either, sometimes it's OK to have multiple questions so that a search has a better chance of finding a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because `cin>>t` doesn't read the end-of-line. The first time you call `getline` you're getting an empty string.

I can think of a couple of ways of getting around this offhand. First is to skip over the whitespace at the end of the first number, since a newline counts as whitespace. Unfortunately this will also skip whitespace at the beginning of the next line.

```
cin >> t >> std::ws;
```

The other way is to use `getline` to skip past the end of the line and ignore the string you get back.

```
cin >> t;
getline(cin, str, '\n');
```

Comment: so what should i do to get rid of it

Comment: thanks for solution ...first way works well...but i have not understood what this ws work....can we use it with like cin>>ws;  to remove white space or it is doing something else

Comment: @vikas2cc Read the marked duplicate. It contains all of the information you need.